# Visualizing what airlines fly in the US Airports

Tags: uses-of-open-data

I am interested in understanding which US airports are used by various airlines.  One could visualize this with a spreadsheet:

[image]
​
​

This examples shows that Southwest flies out of Midway, but not O'Hare.  Delta flies out of O'Hare, but not Midway.  Both fly out of Baltimore.

I'm wondering if there is a clever way to tease out a matrix from openflights.org.

**A spreadsheet would be preferable although, I suspect that if the data is out there, it is stored in a RDBMS.**

Comment: the 'teasing' is actually just programming, so I'm marking this to close because it's actually a programming question. More details below

Comment: i'm confused because gatorback is asking for a spreadsheet. i'm assuming it would take programming to make said spreadsheet?

Comment: The spreadsheet is merely a visualization tool to present data examples.    Other useful visualization \ analytical tools include MATLAB.  That data is really the focus and the encoding of the data (CSV, .mat, etc).  This is not a programming question of how to visualize the data.  I am indifferent to how data is stored / encoded, though standard encoding simplifies loading data into spreadsheets and other analytical tools

Answer (score 3):

The data you are looking for is already at [openflights.org/data](http://openflights.org/data.html). The reason it's not displayed as a matrix (pivot table, non-normalized, crosstab) is that there are 9'541 listed airports and 19'845 listed airlines and creating a sparse matrix is neither good for storage space, performance, user-queries, etc. One reason is that you've used a piece of data, the airport name, as a column name. So you can't easily make a dynamic filter.

Anyway, to create a matrix you'll need to know some programming, or a spreadsheet tool like Excel.

First, download the [airlines.dat](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpatokal/openflights/master/data/airlines.dat) file. Each airline is given a 3-letter code (key).

Then, download the [routes.dat](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpatokal/openflights/master/data/routes.dat) file (2 MB) and use the airlines.dat 3-letter code to join the airline name to the airline code.

Then you need to de-normalize the data, which is a fancy way to make a pivot. Each SQL-flavor, excel, and programming languages can do this in their own way.

---

In my opinion, because the data is easily found and with a friendly license, I'm going to suggest closing the question. I'd recommend starting with a programming or Excel solution and then ask in the appropriate forum if you need support.